# C++: Sum of two custom objects, avoid double call of copy constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-overloading, copy-constructor

In the example below I have two classes, the first one dynamically allocates an integer, the second is a container for the first class.

When I sum two container objects (`operator+()`), the copy constructor is called two times. Seems to me that the second one happens during the "return" statement of the `operator+()` function.
**How do I optimize to avoid the second call of the copy constructor?**

Obviously this is representative for more complex applications where I don't want to have to do two deep copies, if logically thinking only the creation of one object is needed for the sum (which is then returned):

(It might seem like it's a lot of code, but it's only operators and constructors to do the sum efficiently. I avoided the destructors to not clutter it even more).

**Main Class**:

```
int main()
{
  NumberContainer a{1};
  NumberContainer b{2};
  NumberContainer c = a + b; // Copy constructor called twice!
  return 0;
}
```

**Number Class:**

```
class Number
{
public:
  int* num;

  Number(int num) : num{new int{num}}
  {}
// Destructor...
};
```

**Container Class:**

```
class NumberContainer
{
private:
  Number _numObj;
public:
  NumberContainer(int num) : _numObj{Number{num}}
  {}

  NumberContainer(const NumberContainer& source) : NumberContainer{*(source._numObj.num)}
  {
    std::cout<<"Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  NumberContainer(NumberContainer&& source) : NumberContainer(*(source._numObj.num))
  {
    std::cout<<"Move constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  NumberContainer& operator=(const NumberContainer& source)
  {
    *(_numObj.num) = *(source._numObj.num);
    std::cout<<"Copy assignment called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  NumberContainer& operator=(NumberContainer&& source)
  {
    _numObj.num = source._numObj.num;
    source._numObj.num = nullptr;
    std::cout<<"Move assignment called" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  NumberContainer& operator+=(const NumberContainer& source)
  {
    *(_numObj.num) += *(source._numObj.num);
    return *this;
  }

  NumberContainer operator+(const NumberContainer& source) const
  {
    NumberContainer copy{*this};
    return copy+=source;
  }
// Destructor...
};
```

Comment: Did you try implementing `operator+` simply as `return NumberContainer(this->number+source.number);`, and thus having guaranteed copy elision in C++17?

Comment: You didn't mention what compiler options you used to build your program.  You should be testing code that is optimized, and not a "debug" or unoptimized build.

Answer (score 1):

There is no great sense to create an intermediate object within the operator +.

```
  NumberContainer operator+(const NumberContainer& source) const
  {
    NumberContainer copy{*this};
    return copy+=source;
  }
```

Define it like

```
  NumberContainer operator+(const NumberContainer& source) const
  {
    return     *(_numObj.num) + *(source._numObj.num);
  }
```

Also the copy constructor could be defined like

```
  NumberContainer(const NumberContainer& source) : _numObj{*(source._numObj.num)}
  {
    std::cout<<"Copy constructor called" << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, are you enforcing a casting from a number to the NumberContainer return value? It seems appropiate here, but as I said before this is a representative example for the case that the class might be much more complex than just having one member variable. How do you tackle it for the general case?

Comment: @MichelHeusser You can return a braced list without creating an intermediate object.